# Converting INT to Hours and Minutes in SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, type-conversion

I need to convert and INT such as 125, to hours and minutes which will be 02:05.

I know I can do this in PHP with the following:

```
date('H:i',mktime(0, 125))
```

but how do I do this in SQL?

I tried

```
SEC_TO_TIME(table.minutes*60)
```

which works but this results in 02:05:00 and I don't want the seconds.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [MySQL TIME_FORMAT function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-format): `TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(table.minutes * 60), '%H:%i')`